attribute status: eDSRecordAlreadyExists error when installing nix on a mac
I am trying to install Devbox shell on an M1 Macbook pro. I get this error when installing nix:

I have tried several options including deleting the _nixbld1 user but I get to the same error everytime I attempt to proceed with the installing. Could anyone have an idea of how I can solve the issue.

Turns out the issue is happening on MacOs Sequoia beta versions.
The solution is listed in this thread.
If you had already attempted the install, you need to first uninstall nix by following the instructions in this link.
You then re-install using this command:
NIX_FIRST_BUILD_UID="331" sh <(curl -L https://nixos.org/nix/install)

I hope this answer saves someone time.
